# C# progress bar not updating with backgroundworker

Tags: c#, encryption, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I am trying to create an Encryption/Decryption GUI and I have all the functionalities I want. The problem is that I'm trying to get the progress bar running while I am encrypting a file. I searched for articles online and they all told me to use backgroundWorker so the progress bar can run on a separate thread while not freezing up the UI interface. However, I can't seem to get the progress bar to show anything.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   static string key = "";
   cSecureData ed = new cSecureData(key);

   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeEncryptBG();
    }

    private void InitializeEncryptBG()
    {
        encryptBG.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(encryptBG_DoWork);
        encryptBG.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(encryptBG_RunWorkerCompleted);
        encryptBG.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(encryptBG_ProgressChanged);
    }

   private void btnEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        this.btnEncrypt.Enabled = false;
        this.btnDecrypt.Enabled = false;
        /*if (Rijndael.Checked == true)
        {
            ed.EncryptFile(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, "1");
        }
        else if (TripleDES.Checked == true)
        {
            ed.EncryptFile(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, "2");
        }*/
        encryptBG.RunWorkerAsync();
   }

   private void encryptBG_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   {
        if (Rijndael.Checked == true)
        {
            ed.EncryptFile(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, "1");
        }
        else if (TripleDES.Checked == true)
        {
            ed.EncryptFile(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, "2");
        }
        FileInfo fInfo1 = new FileInfo(textBox1.Text);
        FileInfo fInfo2 = new FileInfo(textBox2.Text);
        double totSize = fInfo1.Length;
        double curSize = fInfo2.Length;
        while (curSize <= totSize)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            double percentage = curSize / totSize * 100;
            encryptBG.ReportProgress((int)percentage);
        }
   }

   private void encryptBG_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
   {
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
   }

   private void encryptBG_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
        btnEncrypt.Enabled = true;
        btnDecrypt.Enabled = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Done");
   }
}
```

My encryption method is not here because I'm referencing the method from another project I made.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
while (curSize <= totSize)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    double percentage = curSize / totSize * 100;
    encryptBG.ReportProgress((int)percentage);
}
```

Nothing changes the value of `curSize` or `totSize` inside that `while` loop, so you've got an infinite loop. The value of `percentage` is the same on every iteration, so your `ProgressBar` is never going to change value and will appear "stuck".

You need to figure out what's supposed to happen inside that loop and modify the value of `curSize` such that the percentage changes, the `ProgressBar` moves, and the loop eventually ends.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see where you have bound the encryptBG_ProgressChanged method to the encryptBG event. Usually an event binding would be something like ".OnProgressChanged += encryptBG_ProgressChanged..." in your code

That part of your code isn't visible here, so that could be a place to look.